# getting total number of every extension in whole directory tree

Tags: c#

we have a hardrive with hundreds of thousands of files

i need to figure out how many of every file extension we have

how can i do this with c#?

i need it to go through every directory. this lawyers at my company need this. it can be a total for the entire hardrive it does not have to be broken down by directory

example:

```
1232 JPEG
11 exe
45 bat
2342 avi
532 doc
```

Comment: Has to be a recursive algorithm?.....Sounds like the prof is looking for a particular answer....

Comment: @kevi what i meant is that it has to go through every direectory

Comment: Let's try it this way. You tell us how you think it would work and we can help you go from there.

Comment: On cellphone, so answering's a bit difficult, but I would like to say that when working with hundreds of thousands of files you need to consider memory. My advice is to use a queue, populate it with the base dir, and run until empty. Every run should populate the queue with it's child directories, than scan for files in the current directory. If you use a recursive algorithm, you might get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
string path = @"D:\folder";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .GroupBy(p => Path.GetExtension(p));

foreach (var item in files)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " : " + item.Count());
```

**Edit**: And recursively to loop through the sub directories:

```
Dictionary<string, int> extensions = new Dictionary<string, int>();

Action<string> CalcFilesCount = null;

CalcFilesCount = f =>
     {
         var files = Directory.GetFiles(f).GroupBy(p => Path.GetExtension(p));

         foreach (var ex in files)
         {
             if (extensions.Keys.Contains(ex.Key))
                 extensions[ex.Key] += ex.Count();
             else
                 extensions[ex.Key] = ex.Count();
         }

         foreach (var p2 in Directory.GetDirectories(f))
             CalcFilesCount(p2);
     };

CalcFilesCount(path);

foreach (var   item in extensions)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " :" + item.Value);
```

Good luck!

Comment: @homa will this look through all the subdirectories?

Comment: I slightly better/faster solution would be to use the new method EnumerateFiles, since it won't build up an array of all files in the folder (in this case hundreds of thousands apparently) before it can start processing. However, with a group by (which is required) I'm not sure of the implications

Comment: @homam this works amazingly well, however some directories are either restricted or denied like C:\System Volume Information ... how do i get around this? how do i just skip these files?

Comment: @JOE SKEET, try my approach; you can enclose subdirectory search into an try..catch block and skip those directories where you don't have permission to search or filter them based on a list

Comment: @Shiv: You don't necessarily need to use group, you can do AsParallel().ForAll with a dictionary. That way you get less memory consumption and multithreading!

Comment: @rubens please see comment i left

Comment: @JOE SKEET: I think you can't by this way skip these files, as Rubens Farias says, you can loop through them recursively.

Comment: @homam thank you very much how would i do this can u update your answer please. thank you so much for your help

Comment: @JOE SKEET: Ok, give me some minutes please :)

Comment: @ Alxandr you're saying use a dictionary to maintain the counts by extension? That's what group by is doing. And you can simply say AsParallel on the files array no?

Comment: @JOE SKEET: I edited my answer, you can now put your try-catch block to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Shiv: Good point. GroupBy runs on an IEnumerable, and not on a array, so it's probably made so that it doesn't have everything in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use :

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments // for example
    ); 
var allExt = from f in Directory.GetFiles(
                 folder, 
                 "*.*",
                 SearchOption.AllDirectories // The key concept is here
                 )
             group f by Path.GetExtension(f) into fileWithExt
             let Count = fileWithExt.Count()
             orderby  Count descending
             select new { Ext = fileWithExt.Key, Count}
             ;

foreach (var item in allExt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Ext, item.Count);
}
```

[Edit] did not see the count requirement.... code updated

Comment: it has to return the extension

Comment: @Joe skeet: it's because some folder are system-protected an you won't be able to change that. In this case, take a look at the solution from Rubens (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903600/getting-total-number-of-every-extension-in-whole-directory-tree/4903667#4903667) you will need a bit of adaptation to skip protected directory

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about memory consumption, try this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var extension in files.GroupBy(Path.GetExtension))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} file(s)", extension.Key, extension.Count());
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you do care, you'll need to build an recursive algorithm to navigate through those folders, like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, int> extensions = new Dictionary<string, int>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    recurseFolders(@"c:\");
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> extension in extensions)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} file(s)", extension.Key, extension.Value);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void recurseFolders(string path)
{
    string[] files= Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var extension in files.GroupBy(Path.GetExtension))
    {
        if(!extensions.ContainsKey(extension.Key))
            extensions.Add(extension.Key, extension.Count());
        else
            extensions[extension.Key] += extension.Count();
    }

    foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        recurseFolders(directory);
}
```

Comment: for the first suggestion i am getting this errior: Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 56 39 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: If you read my comment at OP you get another efficient and memory effective aporoapproach. Then you only need 1 dictionary.

Comment: I don't know that approach @Alxandr, but I'll try to build something right now

Comment: @Rubens: It's simple actually. In short. Str currentdir; new  dictionary(); new queue(); q.enqueue(basedir); while(q.Len){currentdir=q.dewueue(); q.enqueue(subdirs in loop); for(f in dir) d[f.extension]++;}

Comment: @Alxandr, I understood that; but I suppose we need to use a background thread to consume that queue, or that's is similar to my second approach

Comment: @Rubens: No need for 2 threads. Just translate what i wrote to code, put it in a function, and return the dictionary, and it *should* work. Though I might be mistaken. As said, not with a pc here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if c# is a requirement, but you can also achieve the same result with a powershell command :

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Group-Object -Property extension
```

Comment: yes powershell is fine too! how do i use this?? can yiou give me an example please

Comment: @joe skeet; just run the command above. I'm not a powershell guru I won't be able to help you more in this direction. Maybe you can ask on http://superuser.com